# How do I create an empty SKSpriteNode in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

How do I create an empty `SKSpriteNode` in Swift? I need a `SKSpriteNode` which I can add `SKSpriteNode`

children to.

The equivalent of this in Objective-C:

```
SKSpriteNode *textSprite = [SKSpriteNode new];
```

Comment: If you want an "empty" node and have no intention of giving it a texture later on you should use SKNode, not SKSpriteNode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let type inference do the work of figuring out the type:

```
var textSprite = SKSpriteNode()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var textSprite: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
```